# Building boost with less headers

Tags: boost, build

I am currently trying to build boost 1.53 with only the minimum required packages.
Here is the command line I use (on windows) to compile boost.

```
b2^
 install^
 --prefix=%BOOST_OUTPUT_DIR%^
 --includedir=%BOOST_INCLUDE_DIR%^
 --toolset=%BOOST_TOOLSET%^
 --link=%BOOST_LINK%^
 --threading=%BOOST_THREADING%^
 --address-model=%BOOST_ADDRESS_MODEL%^
 --runtime-link=%BOOST_RUNTIME_LINK%^
 --build-dir=%BOOST_BUILD_DIR%^
 --without-atomic^
 --without-chrono^
 --without-context^
 --without-date_time^
 --without-exception^
 --without-filesystem^
 --without-graph^
 --without-graph_parallel^
 --without-iostreams^
 --without-locale^
 --without-math^
 --without-mpi^
 --without-program_options^
 --without-python^
 --without-random^
 --without-serialization^
 --without-signals^
 --without-system^
 --without-test^
 --without-thread^
 --without-timer^
 --without-wave

rem --without-regexp^
```

This exemple works in the way that I only compile the regex package but it seems that all the headers of all the removed packages are still added to the output Include directory.

Does anybody knows if it is possible to not have the headers of the removed packages into the output Include directory ?

Comment: I didn't know BCP, i will give it a try, thanks.

Comment: what is your ultimate goal?

Comment: I am using a middleware that makes use of boost but only few classes, I would like to slim boost a lot to only keep what I need from it.